# Execute commands using sudo in remote server after logging into PuTTY through batch file

Tags: ssh, unix, shell, putty

I need to login into remote server daily and perform same set of tasks. I am using Windows platform and the remote server is Unix. I use PuTTY to login 
to remote server. To reduce the manual work, I need to automate this task.

I tried this code:

```
start putty.exe -ssh -load session -l username -pw password -m command.txt -t
```

The `command.txt` contains:

```
sudo su - user1 
ls 
cd directory
```

Only the first command in `command.txt` is working and then PuTTY is expecting input from user.

I need all the commands to be run without user input.

Things that matters :

- I am not root user
- Access granted to switch to the `user1` without    password
- I have a constraint of using PuTTY only (Plink installation is not
  permitted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the commands that are contained in the `command.txt` are executed by *a master shell* one-by-one.

So the master shell executes the `sudo`, waits for it to exit, before it proceeds with the other commands (`ls` and `cd`). And the `sudo` does not exit (at least not on its own).

While you want the `ls` and `cd` to execute within *a child shell* executed by the `su`.

You have to tell the `su` to execute the commands.

This should work:

```
sudo su - -c "ls ; cd directory" user1
```

or this

```
echo "ls; cd directory" | sudo su - user1
```

---

Though I expect that you actually want to continue working in the shell. While the above will exit once the commands are executed.

So you want to add a shell to the list of commands:

```
sudo su - -c "ls ; cd directory ; /bin/bash" user1
```

or

```
echo "ls ; cd directory ; /bin/bash" | sudo su - user1
```